# group-adjacent syntax advice needed

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have following xml (simplified for the purpose)

```
<content>
<p1>blabla</p1>
<p2>blabla</p2>
<p2>blabla</p2>
<p1>blabla</p1>
<p3>blabla</p3>
<p1>blabla</p1>
<p2>blabla</p2>
<p2>blabla</p2>
<p1>blabla</p1>
<p3>blabla</p3>
<p2>blabla</p2>
</content>
```

and I'd like to group all p1 elements and p2 elements, but the latter only if the previous sibling is a p1 element.

I used following xslt :

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="self::p1 or (self::p2 and preceding-sibling::p1[1])">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                            <ol_coll>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>

                            </ol_coll>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
```

but I'm overlooking something in my syntax as it doesn't look at the first previous element but at the whole tree. So I get following return

```
<content>
<ol_coll>
    <p1>blabla</p1>
    <p2>blabla</p2>
    <p2>blabla</p2>
    <p1>blabla</p1>
</ol_coll>
<p3>blabla</p3>
<ol_coll>
    <p1>blabla</p1>
    <p2>blabla</p2>
    <p2>blabla</p2>
    <p1>blabla</p1>
</ol_coll>
<p3>blabla</p3>
<ol_coll>
    <p2>blabla</p2>
</ol_coll>
  </content>
```

but what I was hoping for is the following :

```
<content>
<ol_coll>
    <p1>blabla</p1>
    <p2>blabla</p2>
</ol_coll>
<p2>blabla</p2>
<p1>blabla</p1>
<p3>blabla</p3>
<ol_coll>
    <p1>blabla</p1>
    <p2>blabla</p2>
</ol_coll>
<p2>blabla</p2>
<p1>blabla</p1>
<p3>blabla</p3>
<p2>blabla</p2>
 </content>
```

Anybody that can point me to my error ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the condition to `preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p1]` and then you need to make sure you don't wrap single elements. So with

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content">
  <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="self::p1 or (self::p2 and preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p1])">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and current-group()[2]">
                            <ol_coll>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>

                            </ol_coll>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each-group>  
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the result you posted (running Saxon 9.4).